# Overlapping tabs in Java

Tags: java, swing

I had design 5 tabs using Swing. Each tab contains 2 or 3 sub tabs. Now the problem is, at run time the text fields in tabs are overlapping. I use the method

```
refreshI18NText(jPanelReceivedForm1A)
```

to refresh the jpanel.
but still I'm getting the problem.

Comment: One reason could be the layout manager that you are (not) using in the tabs. Give us some code ...

Comment: Please don't use uppercase (see your title). It is unpleasant and rude.

Comment: honestly, how do you expect anyone to be able to answer your question? no code except for some unknown pseudo code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you are using the correct layout manager.  The Oracle tutorial is useful for selecting and explaining each layout manager. 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html